# SQL Server performance for many users

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database for many users. All users connect to the same  database using the same connection string (ie. via the same user ID/pwd which is hard coded into the client side application software).

From a processing perspective on the server, will it make any difference connecting to the database with each user having its own USER name configured on the database where the access rights to the database will be the same for all?

Comment: From a security and audit point of view; assigning a logon to each individually user is always a good idea.   How else would you know who had made which changes?  How can you remove access from former employees with a hard coded uid and pwd?  [Stack DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) can probably provide a better answer to your question but I cannot imagine there would be any material difference in performance.

Comment: Users are not changing any data on the database. Database is used for data retrieval only...

Comment: Anyway, you can't control who is seeing what and can't protect certain data from a specific user.